# How do US companies release their public float share counts?

Tags: stocks, shares, yahoo-finance, sec

Looking at AAPL, how does Yahoo Finance calculate that today's float is 4.59B shares?

I was hoping to find SEC filings from AAPL confirming this, but I can only conclude that the float was 5.20B back on March 31, 2017
(from the latest 10-K):
"The aggregate market value of the voting and non-voting stock held by non-affiliates of the Registrant, as of March 31, 2017,
the last business day of the Registrant’s most recently completed second fiscal quarter, was approximately $747,509,000,000."

I tried to total up subsequent SEC "changes in beneficial ownership" filings, but they don't add up right.

And, of course, I don't need to match Yahoo.  Every website seems to give something different, but Yahoo seemed the most reasonable.

Comment: Define "float" - often you'll find it's different  from different providers (if they actually let you know what it means).

Comment: I am sure there are other reports on the SEC website or the Apple website that refer to the float that are more recent than one released 5 quarters ago.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I looked through the quarterlies before I posted the question and couldn't find it...if you're so sure, can you help me find it?  Anyway, Yahoo would need a more systematic method.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to find the reports for a US publicly trading company there are two places to look: The SEC and the company investor relations page.

The SEC EDGAR database has all the reports that the company files with the SEC.

This is the front page:

https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

This URL will show you all the 10-K reports for Apple:

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000320193&type=10-k&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40

The 10-K reports are annual reports the newest one is from 2017-11-03

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019317000070/a10-k20179302017.htm

in many cases the quarterly report (10-Q) has more recent numbers. This URL shows all the reports for Apple:

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000320193&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0

Sites like yahoo finance and google finance get their data from the SEC database becasue it is authoritative, and true.

The 10-Q should have all the information you need to answer your question.

Comment: So, can you find Apple's float?  I already tried this.  I might have missed it, but really did try for hours.

Comment: what part are you missing? The 10K discusses the amount of shares outstanding and the number of RSU's?

Comment: I used the latest 10K in my original question and wanted something more recent.  You even commented you were sure that something was more recent but are now telling me to use that same 10K!  What I'm missing is a specific calculation showing the current float is 4.59B.

Comment: The 10k is from November 2017 your question mentioned March 2017.  Confusion over US date format.