# Where to find the public float in SEC filings

Tags: sec, market-capitalization, electronic-filing

I have been traversing through a company's 10-Q on the EDGAR website and I can't find any mention of a public float, but they have it on Finviz. So how do we find it? Finviz is sometimes/oftentimes delayed to update so I want to get it through the filings. I'm not referring to the number of shares outstanding, which is readily available in the 10-Q.

Comment: Similar: [How do US companies release their public float share counts?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/98496)

Comment: According to this [Finviz help page](https://finviz.com/help/screener.ashx), Finviz calculates the float using this formula:  Float = Shares Outstanding - Insider Shares - Above 5% Owners - Rule 144 Shares.